# Reading in a .txt file to update an already stored 2D char array but not overwriting where the original source has blanks

Tags: arrays, c, file, fopen

So I have a very perplexing issue. I got stuck for a few days so I skipped this step to continue the project. I did this by changing the supplied .txt file to the display the output I needed rather than continue to try an over ride my internally detailed 2D array.

I'm pretty sure I can't submit that amended .txt so the program won't work unless I'm able to work this out.

I need a way to copy a .txt file contents over an existing the 2D array but only update the positions that have a character. The other positions within the .txt file are blank.

.txt file Example;

```
 f  g  s   f
a  b    c  d
  a  b   c d
   abc   d
 f  g  s   f
a  b    c  d
  a  b   c d
   abc   d
a  b    c  d
  a  b   c d
 f  g  s   f
```

and I need to copy those over to a 12x12 char array already stored like the below,

```
    char source[12][12] = {
    " ---------- ",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    " ---------- ",
    };
```

I've successfully used the below code to write the .txt file contents to the screen so I'm hoping there's a way to add a method to the for loop to skip the blank spots in the .txt file and only update the 2D array when there is a character at the same corresponding position within the .txt file.

I've omitted some of the details and cose as it's an assignment but if it helps the characters in the .txt file are only 'o','b' and 'blanks'. Both source and destination are 12x12.

```
for (posX = 0; posX < 12; posX++) {

        for (posY = 0; posY < 12; posY++) {
            printf("%c", source[posX][posY]);
        }
        printf("\n");
```

Appreciate any help, it's got me stumped.

---EDIT---

A massive thanks so far.

I've managed to get the copy from the 10x10 .txt file to 12x13 array copied successfully. Progress..

The good news is think I only now need to worry about the " "(blanks) in the .txt file overwriting the ".", so this should make it much simpler?

I've not yet been able to create a if statement do do that. I've tried a few things but I'm now only guessing and need to be pointed to a source to read to understand how to tell the loop;

If you see a (blank) in .txt @ [posX][posY] - do not update the same [posX][posY] in source and continue to loop.

Any help is very much appreciated. The last and final step is a big one and will need this sorted before I can start on that.

```
 ----------
|f  g  s   |
|a  b    c |
|  a  b   c|
|   abc   d|
| f  g  s  |
|a  b    c |
|  a  b   c|
|   abc   d|
|a  b    c |
|  a  b    |
 ----------

fptr = fopen("XXX.txt", "r");

    for (posX = 1; posX < 11; posX++) {

        for (posY = 1; posY < 11; posY++) {

                fscanf(fptr, "%c", &source[posX][posY]);

        }
                fscanf(fptr, "%c", &newline);

        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

Comment: There is '\n' at the end of line, so may be your string worth of 12 chars exists with 13 chars surprisingly to your text file.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly, then  you are trying to hold only characters only but not '\n', '\r' and white spaces and tabs? Just confirming  to give appropriate answer.

Comment: Hi Jarvis, Apologies had a cracking headache from a days attempt when asking the question. Was worried it would be misleading. 

I'm unsure if '/r' represents '.' & '|' chars but in essence yes. I'd like to keep already defined 2d Array chars that do no have a corresponding 'b' or 'o' in the external .txt file. 

Appreciate all that saw that I incorrectly defined the array at 12 x 12 sorry had changed it to 13x13 but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check if the character is different from the space character **' '**, and if it is different you insert it and if it does not continue the loop.
I don't know how you are accessing the file. But there should be a statement similar to this in the loop:

```
if(currentChar != " "){
  source[posX][posY]
}
```

Comment: Thank - you I'll have a crack at this method. Looks quite simple so probably will work.
If one thing is for sure the hours spend coding these ridiculously simple programs has certainly made me appreciate the every bit of software I've used over the years. This stuff is quite hard.

FYI , Accessing the file by - fptr = fopen("xxx.txt", "r");

Comment: ok, the number of rows and columns is always the same? On the other hand, do you know Awk? Awk can be embedded in C and does these kinds of tasks easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of `source` is too small to hold its initializer, you have UB all over the place.  The string `|..........|` is 12 characters long, so it requires an array of size (at least) 13 to hold it.  Change your initializer to:

```
char source[12][13] = {
    " ---------- ",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    "|..........|",
    " ---------- "
};
```

If your code requires that the size of the array be exactly [12][12], then you cannot use string constants for the initializers.  You would need to do the more verbose:

```
char source[12][12] = {
    { ' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { '|', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '|' },
    { ' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ' }
};
```

(or use string constants to initialize the first 11 chars, and then fill in the tail at run time, but that's a bad idea.)

I'm not sure how standard this is (I believe the `...` is a gnu extension), but some compilers will allow:

```
char source[12][12] = {                                                            
    [0]         = { [0] = ' ', [1 ... 10] = '-', [11] = ' ' },                     
    [1 ... 10 ] = { [0] = '|', [1 ... 10] = '.', [11] = '|' },                     
    [11]        = { [0] = ' ', [1 ... 10] = '-', [11] = ' ' }                      
};
```

Comment: Hi William, sorry poor initial description, the 12x12 is not a constraint but a mistake on my part to realize I have changed the array size by a global definition and that definition would give away my assignment.

Regardless appreciate the alt options. that does look a lot cleaner. I may see if it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is with your data receiving technique. What you are doing is, you are directly putting the data into your array without verifying your conditions whether it contains white space or not.

In order to correct it, do some update in your loop...

```
char ch;
ch = fgetc(fptr); //get a character from file pointer...
```

Answer to your edited part, to do the same thing you need this kind of if statement in your loop if I am getting you correctly... now check the conditions to hold the data in your array.

```
if(ch == " " || ch == "\n" || ch == "\r" || ch == "\t" || ch == "\0")
{
//TODO:
// handle white spaces here and correspondingly '\n','\r','\t'...
// print or do whatever you want to do...
}
else
{
//here we have only characters and update it to corresponding position in array...
source[posX][posY] = ch;
}
```